# Why is the "ref" keyword used with System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, ref

I'm looking at some C# code at the moment and I wanted to check that I'm not going nuts in my understanding of how it should be working.

It's to do with passing around a System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.  Every single method which takes a Message object has a method signature similar to this:

```
void SomeMethod(ref Message message) { ... }
```

What I don't understand is why the "ref" keyword is in there.  As far as my understanding goes, if the method is not going to completely replace the object then it's not needed.

```
void SomeMethod(ref Message message)
{
    message = new Message();
}
```

But if the message, for instance, just adds something else to the headers, or just reads a value from the object then the "ref" keyword is not needed as Message is a reference type.

```
void SomeMethod(Message message)
{
    message.Headers.Add("Some Data");  // This should be fine?
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Agree that it's not apparent why the code takes a `ref` parameter. Maybe some additional context would help.

Comment: I'm afraid that's about as much as I've got, I've looked at the MS documentation and it seems every method which takes an object of this type does so with a "ref" keyword?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, you are likely correct; it is likely that the person who wrote the code added the "ref" in error.

I want to take this opportunity though to make sure that you clearly understand what "ref" means. It means "**make an alias to this variable**".  That is, when you say:

```
M(ref string x) { x = null; }
N(string x) { x = null; }
...
string y = "abc";
N(y);
M(ref y);
```

The call to `N(y)` means *make a copy of the reference that is in y, and put that reference in x*.  The call to `M(ref y)` means *x and y are now both names for the same variable*.  That is, `x` becomes an *alias* for `y`.

It is deeply unfortunate that we chose "ref" as the keyword, because it immediately makes people confused about reference types and value types. **It has nothing whatsoever to do with reference types and value types.**  The "ref" means "*I am referring to another variable*".

The difference between `ref` and `out` is nothing more than `ref` requires that the aliased variable be initialized *before* the call and `out` does not. (Both guarantee that the variable will be initialized *after* the call completes normally.)

Comment: I'm actually inclined to agree with the choice of "ref", as this is representing a double indirection when used with reference types ("reference to a reference"). Conversely, if the keyword were, say, "alias" or "var", or "byname" etc., then the semantic similarity could be the stumbling block...

Comment: @Alan: I see your point. But "ref" really is expressing an *implementation detail*. The fact that yes, this is a reference to a storage location that contains a reference to a storage location is interesting from the point of view of the compiler developer, but it does not say much to the user, who after all has no other way to take advantage of that implementation detail.

Comment: And I see yours. Truth is, one tends to conflate true semantics (as in "reference type") and a particular implementation (as in "reference to storage location") after a while... but yes, using "alias" might have caused fewer misunderstandings with 'ordinary' programmers, while compiler writers know the details anyway.

Comment: So to make sure I'm following you both correctly (thanks for the answers both by the way), using ref is more akin to taking a pointer in C/C++, so in this case the SomeMethod method would look more like "SomeMethod(Message** message)".  I suppose the confusion with this matter was more because the MSDN documentation around this area is scattered with "ref" keywords pretty much everywhere, the only reason I could see for doing that was because the Message class implements IDisposable and that it could be attempting to safeguard against the object being disposed ahead of time?

Comment: @daz-fuller: Actually, I don't see much of a proliferation of 'ref Message' parameters in System.ServiceModel.Channels. There are several 'out Message'-endowed methods for cases when a message is created inside a method returning a bool, a classical case of multiple return values; and where there indeed is 'ref Message', it is used to conditionally replace the message with another descendant inside a method, which is not related to disposal in any obvious way.